# Increase brightness in a part of the display

Tags: video, display

I have a laptop with a damaged screen: while it displays an image, one half of it is darker than the other half.

Is there any tool to increase the brightness of only a single part of the display?

I managed to make things slightly better by playing with `xgamma`, but it's not quite what I want.

Comment: If there was, it probably wouldn't yield satisfactory results. Either the illumination source is damaged or the lcd is, and will not be able to produce the same luminance or contrast as the undamaged part regardless of how you change the contents of the framebuffer.

Comment: Plug in an external monitor and keyboard, and treat it like a really small desktop computer.